# why this code doesn´t work: jLabel setIcon?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I´m trying to set the icon for a jLabel object and it doesn´t work. I use a method that returns a ImageIcon object if the .getClass().getResource(path) is different from null, and if the resource is null it display a message "The resource couldn´t be found: path to the file", but the file is there!!!. If i don´t select a file a default ImageIcon is apply instead and this work without problems. I don´t know why this doesn´t work.

```
 private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        JFrame upFile = new JFrame();
        File fichero = new File("");
        File x = new File("");
        CopyFile copy= new CopyFile();
        JFileChooser upfile = new JFileChooser(fichero.getCanonicalPath());
        int op = upfile.showOpenDialog(upFile);
                if (op == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    fichero = upfile.getSelectedFile();
                    File destino = new File(x.getCanonicalPath()+"\\src\\img\\libros_fotos\\"+fichero.getName());
                    copy.copyFile(fichero, destino);
                    SetLibro("/img/libros_fotos/"+destino.getName());
                    jLabel47.setIcon(createImageIcon(GetLibro()));
                    // commented out as suggested
                    //this.revalidate();
                    //this.repaint();
                }
                else {SetLibro("/img/blank.jpg");
                      jLabel47.setIcon(createImageIcon(GetLibro()));
                    // commented out as suggested
                    //this.revalidate();
                    //this.repaint();                            }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `createImageIcon(GetLibro())` do you return `Icon`?

Comment: Yes i return a ImageIcon object or null.

Comment: `private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
            } else {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + path);
            return null;
    }
}` It returns null or an Imageicon object.

Comment: did you repaint in `else` too? if no, put it there as well

Comment: Inside the `if` and `else` statements as well, but still doesn´t work.

Comment: `JLabel47` gives me a bad smell in the code :-) Why not use an array, why this weird name ? Hope you not using `JLabel1` till `JLabel46`. Though you really don't have to use `revalidate/repaint`, `JLabel.setIcon()` will take care of that implicitly. Had you tried using `destino.getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: I don´t use an array becouse i´m only working with this single JLabel object. When i use `destino.getAbsolutepath()` i get the same error from `getResource(path)`, File not found, but the file is there!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
this.revalidate();  
this.repaint();
```

after adding Icon

Comment: I mean when i check: `if (op == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)` if it´s `TRUE` the `ImageIcon` object is the picture i have selected, if it´s `FALSE` the `ImageIcon` object is selected by default: `else {SetLibro("/img/blank.jpg");
 jLabel47.setIcon(createImageIcon(GetLibro()));
 }`. I follow your advice and put the `this.repaint()` just after the `SetIcon(createImageIcon(GetLibro()))` inside the if statement. But it works the first time i Run the project but not anymore.

Comment: @mKorbel: did you mean: `getIconImage().flush();`? becouse it doesn´t work.

Comment: @MaximShoustin `this.revalidate();` and `this.repaint();`. Still not working.

Comment: @Eddy post all your code, I cant detect the problem from snippets